# CVS: List all files changed between tags (or dates)

Tags: cvs

Is there any way to list all the files that have changed between two tags in CVS?

Every time we do a release we apply a tag to all the files in that release. I want to find all the files that changed between releases.

It would also work if I could find all files that had changed between two dates.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I suppose this command would help:

```
cvs diff -N -c -r RELEASE_1_0 -r RELEASE_1_1 > diffs
```

where `RELEASE_1_0` and `RELEASE_1_1` are the names of your tags.

You can find a little more information on cvs diff command [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/cvsmanual/diffexamples.html)

plus it should be fairly simple to create a script to make report more suitbable for your needs, ex: number of files changed, created deleted etc. As far as I know the most common cvs GUI tools (wincvs and tortoise) do not provide something like this out of the box.

Hope it helps `;)`

Comment: There's a perl script called cvs2cl which can produce nice formatted versions of logs, either as the finished report or as text or XML to post-process: http://www.red-bean.com/cvs2cl/

Comment: Just found this via Google and it saved me a load of work, thanks a lot!
I was trying to find out via the 'history' command, forgot about diff.

Comment: `-N` gives error on a Windows machine: `cvs [server aborted]: Cannot use reserved filename 'nul' on NT based machines`

Answer (score 24):

I prefer using `rdiff` and `-s` option

```
cvs rdiff -s  -r RELEASE_1_0 -r RELEASE_1_1 module > diffs
```

`rdiff` does not require a sandbox; `-s` gives you a summary of the changes.

Comment: I tried most other options here, and with the others I couldn't catch all the changes.  Thanks!

Comment: This one is good. 'cvs rdiff -s -rvxxxxx -rHEAD module 2>/dev/null' Gives a summary "File <file> (changed from|is new) ...."

Answer (score 17):

To get the list of files between two dates using CVS:

```
cvs diff -N -c -D YYYY-MM-DD -D YYYY-MM-DD | grep "Index:" > diff.out
```

More information on accepted dates for the -D flag: http://docs.freebsd.org/info/cvs/cvs.info.Common_options.html

Answer (score 11):

To get a list of files that have changed between one version and another using the standard cvs commands:

```
cvs -q log -NSR -rV-1-0-69::V-1-0-70 2>/dev/null >log.txt
```

Or alternatively, to get a list of commit comments just drop the `-R`:

```
cvs -q log -NS -rV-1-0-69::V-1-0-70 2>/dev/null >log.txt
```

Where you replace `V-1-0-69` and `V-1-0-70` with the revisions you're comparing.

Comment: The last command was what I was looking for :) Just added a little grep to filter out the lines I don't want: grep -vE "^branch|^RCS|^head|^locks|^access|^keyword|^total|^description|^revision"

Comment: This is good for file changes. Same flags work with cvs rlog. You can use 'cvs -q log -NS -rvxxxx::' to show changes since last tag which is handy. For files added after tag you get a "warning: no revision " and you do not get shown the cvs add or commit comments.

Answer (score 9):

```
cvs log -d ">=DATE" -N -S -R > cvs.log
```

Comment: **Example**: `cvs -q log -NSRd ">=2013-10-20"`. Remove `R` if you also want the commit summaries.

Answer (score 4):

DLira's method gives a lot of detail, including all the changes.

To just get a list of files, this works:

```
cvs diff -N -c -r RELEASE_1_0 -r RELEASE_1_1 | grep "Index:" > diffs
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to comment on the verbosity and how get just what you want. But you are right! grep is a great way to get only what you need. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best tool I've found for this is a perl script called [cvs2cl.pl](http://www.red-bean.com/cvs2cl/).  This can generate a change list in several different formats.   It has many different options, but I've used the tag-to-tag options like this:

```
cvs2cl.pl --delta dev_release_1_2_3:dev_release_1_6_8
```

or

```
cvs2cl.pl --delta dev_release_1_2_3:HEAD
```

I have also done comparisons using dates with the same tool.